# Gentzen-style proof tree

Tags: trees, mathjax, logic

I would like to produce the following proof tree. This is my current attempt:

```
\def\ae\qquad\mathbf{\forall Elim}
\def\ai\qquad\mathbf{\forall Intro}
\def\be\qquad\mathbf{\leftrightarrow Elim}
\def\bi\qquad\mathbf{\leftrightarrow Intro}
\def\oe\qquad\mathbf{\lor Elim}
\def\oi\qquad\mathbf{\lor Intro}
\def\ne\qquad\mathbf{\neg Elim}
\def\ni\qquad\mathbf{\neg Intro}

\begin{equation}
\dfrac{
  \dfrac{
    \dfrac{
      \dfrac{
        \dfrac{\forall x(Pa \lor Rx)}{Pa \lor Rb}\ae
          \dfrac{\dfrac{Pa}{Pa \lor \forall xRx \quad \lnot(Pa \lor \forall xRx)}}{Rb \qquad Rb}\ne
          }{
            Rb
          }\oe
          }{
            \forall xRx
          }\ai
        }{
          Pa \lor \forall xRx  \quad \lnot(Pa \lor \forall xRx)
        }\oi
      }{
    Pa \lor \forall xRx
}\ne
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Would be possible to not extend fraction line in this two sections of the tree ?

[image]

So, in the first case, for example, that line would look:

[image]

Perhaps, there is a better route for solving this problem. I will be using MathJax.

Comment: For MathJax I don't know (that is off-topic on the site by the way) but for LaTeX there are various packages for this kind of proofs, see for example https://www.logicmatters.net/latex-for-logicians/nd/.

Comment: I am wondering if it's possible without a package. Nevertheless, thank you for the links, @Marijn.

Comment: If it's possible with a package, it is possible without one. You can always put the package's code in your document, after all. There's not much reason to do this, though.

Comment: Thanks for the input, @cfr.